# Selenium webdriver: IE 11 sendKeys - select all(Ctrl+A) text in input (textbox)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I have method to select text using (Ctrl+A) which I use in automated tests.

```
public static void SelectText(IWebElement input)
{
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.Click(input).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a").Perform();
}
```

In Chrome and Firefox method `SelectText` (working). But in IE 11 is not working.
In IE it only types "a".

For example: In input is text "lorem ipsum". In IE this method appends 'a' to end of the value  "lorem ipsuma".

My configuration:
Windows 8.1, Selenium version 2.46.0, IEDriverServer.exe (x86 version).

IE initialization

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.EnableNativeEvents = false;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you re-frame the sentences please?

Comment: Does the application do a continuous post after each character that you typed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a browser switch, when running for IE11 I use the following code to select all:

```
input.SendKeys(""); // focus element
SendKeys.SendWait ("^a"); // use windows to send input
```

Comment: Thank you :). This is working. I have one question. Why I can use selenium method? It's selenium bug or IE bug?

Comment: I'm also not 100% sure. I guess the problem has to do with the InternetExplorerWebDriver implementation. The driver is very hacky due to IE's COM interface being a pain in the ass (big thanks to Jim Evans for keeping this project alive anyways). We all hope it gets better when Microsoft releases its own, native, WebDriver implementation for IE. Oh, pardon, for "Edge" of course.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that try using [ASCII Code](http://www.unix-manuals.com/refs/misc/ascii-table.html) and use `Build().Perform()` isntead of `Perform()` alone

```
  char c = '\u0001'; // ASCII code 1 for Ctrl-A

  actions.Click(input).SendKeys(Convert.ToString(c)).Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer this works for me

```
Actions actions = new Actions(_driver);
            actions.Click(IWebElement);
            actions.Click(cellProjectName).SendKeys("GU" + "Project" + "-" + consecutiveProjects).Perform();
```

in C#

Answer (score -1):

I'm using .NET, and this is what worked for me:

```
input.SendKeys(Keys.Control & "a")
```